# Is there a limit on the size of column qualifier in hbase

Tags: c#, hbase, thrift

I am storing the proto serialized data of about 5 KB in Hbase as a column in a column family. When I try to get the row the function does not return . I am using the thrift APIs from C#. But if I serialize a relatively lesser sized data it works fine. Is there any limit on the size of the value of a column qualifier.

Comment: Maybe it's me, but how likely is it that any limit whatsoever on the column names length will lead to a hanging call if the column data content is larger? Or are you saying, that the column name is the data? Even then, I would expect an error return. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: Have you read http://hbase.apache.org/book/perf.schema.html and especially 6.3.2 from http://hbase.apache.org/book/rowkey.design.html?

Comment: Here I'm talking about the value of the column not the name of the column. The column name is say for example 'Data' and the value is a proto serialized object.

Comment: 5KB sounds not like a lot of data to me

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's an actual limit. The recommendation is to save data in HDFS when cell sizes exceed 10MB ([see the FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/FAQ_Design#A3)). In systems I worked on we've used 5MB cells without a problem.

I am guessing the problem you are seeing has to do with the Thrift server to the Thrift C# integration